# How does one utilize AppDomains in an ASP.NET 4 WebForm application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

**AppDomains in IIS/ASP.NET**

Given an ASP.NET WebForms portal being hosted within IIS and the use of isolated modules written in ASP.NET MVC3, what is the appropriate API to use in executing the modules during runtime?

1. AppDomain API
2. ApplicationHost API
3. AppManagerAppDomainFactory class
4. Not appropriate, use IIS built-in isolation mechanisms and find another way to host MVC3-generated content in a portal's MasterPage structure
5. ??

---

**Background**

We have a legacy custom portal with a number of applications hosted written using C#/WebForms.  Currently, the portal and all applications live in a single project; they are all deployed at the same time. I would like to separate the applications from the portal, implement them as modules to the portal, and to isolate the execution of each module during run-time. We would like to port/rewrite each application in ASP.NET MVC 3.

As we port each application, my initial thinking is have the portal handle each request, load the app/module in an AppDomain, forward requests to the module, obtain the generated html, and place it in the portal MasterPage's ContentPlaceHolder. Before I go down this path, I thought it prudent to get some StackOverflow validation on the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Isolating plugins/modules into a separate AppDomain is useful when the plugins are provided by a 3rd party and you want to apply strict security restrictions on the plugin.  When you've written the plugins yourself, this level of isolation isn't necessary and is counter productive.

You can achieve the necessary level of isolation through appropriate project references.  Define a separate project which contains the interfaces for the plugin API and any associated value objects.  Have your plugins reference this project and implement the appropriate API's.  Then your host application should reference the plugins only through this API.  That gives you code separation and easier maintenance without dealing with managing multiple AppDomains.

Comment: Thanks @Samuel. Great answer, and well worth considering. I'm exploring isolation as transition technique. I'm concerned less about security; more about memory & stability. I have already created a new app (in WebForms) that makes use of dependency injection and a number of other 3rd party libs. The DI is init'ed via WebActivator (which now runs anytime the portal rns and can bring it down). Also static classes, libraries, assemblies for each app are loaded for the life of the helper process. The portal is used all day, it would be nice if module-specific memory is released throughout the day.

Comment: @Jason, it sounds like you're trying to optimize for a problem you don't have yet and may never have. Write it the way it makes sense for your needs and then profile the app to see what needs to be optimized. Besides that, you can always recycle the asp.net app on a schedule for quick and dirty resource release.